# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: TypeError: JSON.stringify is not a function using selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, json, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with C# and trying to enter card details in 3rd party payment page. While navigating from one page of 3rd party payment page to another I'm getting above mentioned runtime error.

Firstly as the 3rd party payment screen gets load, I'm Click on element of the same page which is getting clicked successfully by following line code

```
public static void WhenClicksOnTheElementUsingJavscript(string userAlias, string cssSelector)
    {
        UserManager.SetCurrentUser(userAlias);
        var element = WebDriverManager.CurrentWebDriver.AttemptToFindElement(cssSelector);
        WebDriverManager.CurrentWebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
    }
```

but as soon as button got clicked and i redirect to next page It throws:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.callFunctionOn threw exception: TypeError: JSON.stringify is not a function
```

above error and I'm not able to enter card details in the current loaded page

Due to runtime error I'm not able to enter card details on currently loaded page

Comment: The error originates in the JavaScript that executes when clicking the element. You will need to include debugging details from the browser itself. Can you perform the use case manually without JavaScript errors? Maybe you found a bug in the web page that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yeah but isn't there any alternate way through which we can make automation work without solving this issue on developer side.